# Starting Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think easiest part left for me but I can't handle. I wrote a procedure:

```
create procedure wstawsiatke
     (@doc_id int)
as
begin
    update documents
    set Doc_LongStringColumn4 = (select 
                                     case when sum(elm_intcolumn1) <= 2 
                                            then 'gry nie bedzie' 
                                            else 'gra bedzie'  
                                     end 
                                 from Documents
                                 join Elements on doc_id = ELM_ObjectID
                                 where 
                                     doc_id = @doc_id and ELM_FflID = 262)
    where doc_id = @doc_id
end
```

And now I have problem with executing this procedure.

When I execute

```
exec wstawsiatke @doc_id = 150
```

it will work but I want to make it automatically to new documents. I am using this in program

Comment: Can you please provide some more details? What do you mean by "Automatically to new document.", as well whenever you post some question, please provide some sample data so that one regenerate the same.

Comment: So if it is a new document it will have 0 for @doc_id for example, and in this scenario you would want to insert the data rather than updating?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: your question is not very clear.

Comment: It sounds like you want to setup a trigger that whenever the table documents has a new record inserted this runs?